# Use p4v to untag files?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I am using p4v windows client and I want to untag files.
On command line it would be 
`p4 tag -d -l <tagname> <filenames>`

How can i do this in p4v?

---

In response to one of the answers...
There *IS* a difference between `p4 label` and `p4 tag`

`Running p4 label allows you to configure the mapping that controls the set of files that are allowed to be included in the label. After configuring the label, use p4 labelsync or p4 tag to tag files with the label.`

from http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/label.html

see also http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/tag.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the file, and go to `Label...` Then select the file in the Files/Folders: section, and click remove.

Comment: It seems there are some differences between Labels and Tags. I will post more info